# How to change the font face of the current buffer?

Tags: fonts, aquamacs

I am using tex-mode in Aquamacs and would like to temporarily change the font for the current buffer. What is the way to do it? I tried:

```
(set-face-attribute "American Typewriter" nil :height 150)
```

which gives the error:

```
eval: Wrong type argument: symbolp, "American Typewriter"
```

even though "American Typewriter" is in `(font-family-list)`. When I try:

```
(set-face-attribute "American Typewriter" nil :height 150)
```

it only affects the font of the minibuffer, not the current buffer I have open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `buffer-face-set`, which accepts either a face name like `(buffer-face-set "error")` or a property list of face attributes and values like `(buffer-face-set :weight 'bold :height 150)`.

I think your specific example would be something like `(buffer-face-set :font-family "American Typewriter" :height 150)`.

You can <kbd>M-:</kbd> and at the "Eval:" prompt enter one of those Emacs Lisp expressions. (When I tried, it set the font in the buffer from which I issued the command, as you want -- not the minibuffer.)

---

`buffer-face-set` is also usable as interactive command: <kbd>M-x buffer-face-set</kbd>. The prompt only seems to accept a face name -- not a property list. So, maybe you could use `defface` in your Emacs init file to define a face with the desired properties, to be able to enter that face name.

Answer (score 3):

With respect to what you tried using `set-face-attribute`:

The error message tells you that the first argument needs to be a symbol. At that point you should use `C-h f set-face-attribute`, which tells you that the first argument needs to be a face.

Here's an example of its use.

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil ':font "American Typewriter" ':height 150)
```

That changes the default font (the font for face `default`) for all existing and future frames (second arg `nil`), which is not what you want.  `set-face-attribute is face-specific, not buffer-specific.  The answer for what you want is to use function`buffer-face-set`, as others have indicated.

Answer (score 2):

I use it as buffer local by

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "American typewriter" :height 150))
# eval: (buffer-face-mode t)
# End:
```

Change :height to what you want.